# What does it mean when the Atlas has no info on my exit node?

Tags: atlas

Opened Tor Browser, clicked the test link, then clicked the Atlas link, and was told "No results found"

Another question said that when onionoo is down it would fail, but the message would look more like an error message.

The onion menu still shows what country.